# What library do I have to use such that the document can render \lt and \gt as less than and greater than signs, respectively?

Tags: math-mode, packages

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath} It does Not work !
\begin{document}
\[
x\lt y \gt z
\]
\end{document}
```

What library do I have to use such that the document can render `\lt` and `\gt` as `less than` and `greater than` signs, respectively?

### Edit

I am using MathJax library in my site under Asp.net Mvc 3. Web application is vulnerable to XSS and XSRF attacks so `<` and `>` should be avoided as the input from the users.

My database will save LaTeX commands that can be rendered by both LaTeX compiler and MathJax. Therefore, I need `\gt` and `\lt` that already work in MathJax.

**Source:**

[image]

**Rendered:**

[image]

Comment: Why are you not just use `<` and `>`?

Comment: In general have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: @Martin: I cannot use them in my site. They are vulnerable to XSS and XSRF attacks.

Comment: So you are using LaTeX on a webserver with user input or what? You should mention such things in the question.

Comment: @Martin: see my update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If that's all you want, add

```
\newcommand{\lt}{<}
\newcommand{\gt}{>}
```

to the preamble (before `begin{document}`).
This should allow you to use `\lt`and `\gt`.

Comment: +1, and if you don't want this in the main document put it into your own `.sty` file and load that using `\usepackage`.