# Problems with language?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I don't know why this code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definição}
\begin{document}

\begin{definition}

Um conjunto $H$ com uma operação binária associativa é chamado de semigrupo.

\end{definition}

\begin{definition}

Um semigrupo $H\subset \mathbb{N}$ é chamado de numérico quando $0\in H$, $L=\mathbb{N}-H$ é finito e $1\in L$. Os elementos $1=l_1\lt l_2\ldots\lt l_g$ de $L$ são chamados de lacunas de $H$ e os elementos $0=n_0\lt n_1\lt\ldots$ de $H$ são chamados de não-lacunas de $H$. A quantidade de lacunas de $H$ é chamada de gênero de $H$.

\end{definition}

\begin{definition}

Um semigrupo numérico $H$ é chamado de hiperelíptico quando $n_1=2\in H$.

\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 ... finito e $1\in L$. Os elementos $1=l_1\lt
l_2\ldots\lt l_g$ de $L$ ...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 ...in L$. Os elementos $1=l_1\lt l_2\ldots\lt
l_g$ de $L$ são chamados...
```

It's something to do with the language?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `\lt` command as far as I know. Use `<` instead if you mean that symbol.

Comment: At several places `\lt` is used inside math. What it is supposed to mean?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12519/what-library-do-i-have-to-use-such-that-the-document-can-render-lt-and-gt-as-l

Comment: @user108205: I retagged your question, since it's not connected to languages but to an error due to an unknown macro named `\lt`

Comment: @user108205 One doubt: o/ If you write in Portuguese why don't you load the `babel` or the `polyglossia` packages?

Comment: @Aradnix What are the advantages of these packages?

Comment: Well when you use them you don't need to translate manually the hierarchy macros such as `chapter, section, tableofcontents`, etc. Also gives you the right hyphenation according the rules of your language instead of the English. They are also helpful with the decimal marker you use.

Comment: @user108205 Also it helps you to improve your references if you use also `biblatex`.

Comment: @Aradnix Thank you very much, I didn't know it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, `\lt` should mean *less than*, there is no such command however, as far as I know.

It's easy to define such a command with this meaning, if needed:

```
\newcommand{\lt}{\ensuremath{<}}%
```

There are some commands called `\le` and `\ge` meaning <= etc.

In addition, if needed, a `\gt` can be defined accordingly:

```
\newcommand{\gt}{\ensuremath{>}}%
```

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definição}

\newcommand{\lt}{\ensuremath{<}}%
\begin{document}

\begin{definition}

Um conjunto $H$ com uma operação binária associativa é chamado de semigrupo.

\end{definition}

\begin{definition}

Um semigrupo $H\subset \mathbb{N}$ é chamado de numérico quando $0\in H$, $L=\mathbb{N}-H$ é finito e $1\in L$. Os elementos $1=l_1 \lt l_2\ldots \lt l_g$ de $L$ são chamados de lacunas de $H$ e os elementos $0=n_0\lt n_1\lt\ldots$ de $H$ são chamados de não-lacunas de $H$. A quantidade de lacunas de $H$ é chamada de gênero de $H$.

\end{definition}

\begin{definition}

Um semigrupo numérico $H$ é chamado de hiperelíptico quando $n_1=2\in H$.

\end{definition}

\end{document}
```