# Why it causes this "Undefined control sequence" after "\lt"

Tags: errors

I got this error in using pdflatex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \(1.5 \lt
              x \lt 5.5\)
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \(1.5 \lt x \lt
                    5.5\)
?
```

The tex-file is:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\(1.5 \lt x \lt 5.5\)
\end{document}
```

The sequence "\lt" should represent "<" symbol. But it causes the error.
Should I add some additional packages?

Comment: Where did you find this command?

Comment: Why don't you type `<` in math mode?

Comment: I have faced that command in the math section of gmatclub.com/forum . Most formulas use "<", but some "\lt".

Comment: @FireShock Most likely the forum is about MathJax in which it's actually recommended to use `\lt` and `\gt` because of possible injection of malicious code using `<` and `>`. This is not a problem in TeX.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [What library do I have to use such that the document can render \lt and \gt as less than and greater than signs, respectively?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12519/what-library-do-i-have-to-use-such-that-the-document-can-render-lt-and-gt-as-l) you should define your own commands, because LaTeX can write `<` and `>` in math mode.

But if you use a "normal" TeX document (unlike the OP of the other question) you should have the following commands (note the `\ensuremath`):

```
\newcommand{\lt}{\ensuremath <}
\newcommand{\gt}{\ensuremath >}
```